# Supertest return a different body

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, supertest

I have an e2e test where I test the registration (email unique)

The Test is:

```js
    it('Register a default user: /api/v1/auth/email/register (POST)', async () => {

        return request(app.getHttpServer())
          .post('/auth/email/register')
          .send({
            "name": newUserName,
            "username": newUsername,
            "email": TESTER_EMAIL,
            "password": TESTER_PASSWORD
          })
          .expect(201);
      });
```

The second time, with the same values, I expect a 400 Status code, and I got it.

```js
    it('Register a default user: /api/v1/auth/email/register (POST)', async () => {

        return request(app.getHttpServer())
          .post('/auth/email/register')
          .send({
            "name": newUserName,
            "username": newUsername,
            "email": TESTER_EMAIL,
            "password": TESTER_PASSWORD
          })
          .expect(400)
          .expect(({ body }) => {
            console.log(body);
          });
      });
```

If I analyze the Body, I can see:

```js
     {
          index: 0,
          code: 11000,
          keyPattern: { email: 1 },
          keyValue: { email: 'john.doe@example.com' }
        }
```

and it is correct, Because I have an index unique on my mongoDB.
But I expect the same response that I receive from my production API.

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "username already exist",
    "email already exist"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

The controller is simple, I have a route like:

```js
      @Post('email/register')
      @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED)
      async register(@Body() authRegisterLoginDto: AuthRegisterLoginDto) {
        return this.authService.register(authRegisterLoginDto);
      }
```

In my service:

```js
    async register(authRegisterLoginDto: AuthRegisterLoginDto) {
    
        const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(randomStringGenerator()).digest('hex');
        const user = await this.usersService.create({
          ...authRegisterLoginDto,
          hash,
        });
    
        await this.mailService.userSignUp({
          to: user.email,
          data: {
            hash,
          },
        });
      }
```

and in my userService(wehre I get the error) is:

```js
    async create(userDto: UserDto): Promise<IUsers> {
        try {
          return await this.userModel.create(userDto);
        } catch (err) {      
          throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
      }
```

How can I get the same response that I get from my "prod" API?

UPDATE.

main.ts

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe, VersioningType } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { TransformationInterceptor } from './interceptors/transformInterceptor';
import { TransformError } from './interceptors/transformErrorInterceptor';
import { useContainer } from 'class-validator';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  //added for custom validator
  useContainer(app.select(AppModule), {fallbackOnErrors: true});
  //custom response
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformationInterceptor)
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformError)  
  app.setGlobalPrefix(configService.get('app.apiPrefix'), {
    exclude: ['/'],
  });
  app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API')
    .setDescription('The API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth(
      {
        type: 'http',
        scheme: 'bearer',
        bearerFormat: 'JWT',
        name: 'JWT',
        description: 'Enter JWT token',
        in: 'header',
      },
      'JWT-auth', // This name here is important for matching up with @ApiBearerAuth() in your controller!
    )
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api/doc', app, document);

  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(configService.get('app.port'));

}
bootstrap();
```

jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your tests setup and main.ts file? p.s You can format your code with backticks plus lang name. ````typescript [CODE]```

Comment: @n1md7 thanks a lot, I added the main.ts, and I don't understand which setup you want, I added the Jest conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your E2E test bootstraps the app but make sure all transformation pipes are included and everything else that might be involved altering error response.

To get the same effect in the e2e test always include the setup you have in `main.ts` except swagger docs or some unrelated stuff.

in your case, I'd try this

```js
let app: INestApplication;

beforeEach(async () => {

  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformationInterceptor);
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformError);

  await app.init();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I already tried to import or comment in my main.ts. I have the same problem. Where can I find `E2E test bootstraps`?

Comment: By E2E testing bootstrap, I meant your testing setup. Whatever is included in the snippet I provided in `beforeEach` callback. It was not shown in the question. 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @n1md7, I imported
`useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });`

into my e2e test. I modified it because I want to use the

```js
  @Validate(UniqueValidator, ['username'], {
    message: 'username already exist',
  })
```

in my Dto. ([MongoDB and class-validator unique validation - NESTJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545580/mongodb-and-class-validator-unique-validation-nestjs/71357312#71357312))